# Mac Pro with Thunderbolt Display 30 meters away

Tags: mac, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

We want to position a Thunderbolt Display (2015 model) 30 meters away from a Mac Pro (2015 model).

**Questions regarding this setup:**

1. What cable do we need to connect these two? I have seen Thunderbolt 1 and Thunderbolt 2 cables, can't really see which one we need to connect the display to the Mac Pro
2. Is it possible to connect a keyboard and mouse to the Thunderbolt Display and control the Mac Pro?

**Further explanation of our situation:**

We have a Mac Pro upstairs which has one account of adobe cloud and we have a laptop with the second adobe cloud account. 1 license is limited to 2 computers.

We have 2 Thunderbolt Displays 2 keyboards 2 mouse. We want to use the same Mac Pro in the upstairs office and in the downstairs office which are located right on top of each other. I was thinking of just drilling a whole trough the floor and connecting the second screen via thunderbolt.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a remote desktop / share screen?

Comment: I will have to invest in another Mac for that and the programs are really heavy and not that smooth over remote desktop.

Comment: OK. The latter shouldn't be really noticeable over a fast Gigabit Ethernet. Make sure you deactivate compression in Screensharing options for highest visual quality.

Answer (score 2):

Copper-based Thunderbolt cables are limited to max length of 3 meters. Corning sells [optical Thunderbolt cables](http://www.corning.com/opcomm/OpticalCablesbyCorning/products/thunderbolt.aspx) you will need for the distance you specify here. You can get 10m lengths at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HSTC496) for US$299. They come in 30m and 60m lengths for US$659 and US$1299, respectively. I haven't had the need for these lengths yet, but I did the research a few weeks ago for a project which didn't get off the ground.

Comment: Any comments for the Mouse / Keyboard Question. I see a lot of posts with users which have problems.

Comment: There are numerous IP-based KVM, HD Video & USB systems available. [Black Box](http://www.blackbox.com/Store/results.aspx/kvm/ip-enabled/n-4294955135) is a good place to start.

Comment: Not an option I think? We need 1 Mac Pro with 2 displays and 2 keyboards and 2 Mouses

Comment: KVMs are designed to share a computer with multiple displays/kbds/mice. We have an elaborate IP-based KVM system @ our school which allows several workstations to access all the servers in our racks. Perhaps you should edit your question to more fully explicate exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just did, check it out ^